# POST Request in Python 'requests' module not working properly

Tags: python, http-post, python-requests

```
POST https://maxcvservices.dnb.com/rest/Authentication
x-dnb-user: MyUsername
x-dnb-pwd: MyPassword
```

is the documentation of the D&B API and hence I am trying to send a POST request using python requests module using the following line of code:

```
r = requests.post('https://maxcvservices.dnb.com/rest/Authentication',params={'x-dnb-user':userid,'x-dnb-pwd':pass})
```

the response I am getting is `Response [500]`

and the content of the response is : `error processing request\r\n`

My question is whether I am doing something wrong while passing the post request and the parameters or is it a problem with my username and password being invalid?

I feel the problem lies in the way I am passing the POST request as the API responds with a separate error 401 for incorrect userid, pass.

```
{'connection': 'Keep-Alive',
 'content-encoding': 'gzip',
 'content-length': '46',
 'content-type': 'text/plain',
 'date': 'Sat, 26 Oct 2013 17:43:22 GMT',
 'server': '',
 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding',
 'x-correlationid': 'Id-d4c07ad3526bff3a03fb742e 0'}
```

my response header when I use:

```
r = requests.post('https://maxcvservices.dnb.com/rest/Authentication', headers={'x-dnb-user': 'userid', 'x-dnb-pwd': 'password'})
```

A random user-id and password.

But according to the API I am supposed to receive `<Response [401]>` .
I receive `<Response [500]>` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are HTTP headers; quoting the [API documentation](http://developer.dnb.com/docs/2.0/common/authentication-process):

> Secure access to D&B Direct services is managed through the use of an Authentication Token, which can be obtained by sending an HTTP POST request to Authentication Service URL, passing a valid username and password **in the HTTP header**.

Add them as such:

```
r = requests.post(
    'https://maxcvservices.dnb.com/rest/Authentication',
    headers={'x-dnb-user': userid, 'x-dnb-pwd': password})
```

This works for me, albeit that I get a 401 response (as I don't have any valid credentials):

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests.__version__
'2.0.0'
>>> r = requests.post('https://maxcvservices.dnb.com/rest/Authentication',
...                   headers={'x-dnb-user': 'userid', 'x-dnb-pwd': 'password'})
>>> r
<Response [401]>
>>> r.headers['authorization']
'INVALID CREDENTIALS'
```

entirely as documented.

Comment: I tried that but still got the same 'error processing request' message. Response 500

Comment: @user1009091: are you certain you called this correctly? With a random username and password value, I get a 401 response.

Comment: This is pretty weird I did exactly the same thing not only am I getting <Response [500]> , my response header doesn't even have an authorization key in it.

Comment: What version of `requests` did you install? `requests.__version__` for me is 2.0.

Comment: And did you try the **exact same code** as posted in my sample session? So with the `'userid'` and `'password'` string literals?

Comment: yes I tried the exact same code. And my requests version is 0.14.2 I guess archaic when compared to yours. I shall try updating my requests module and get back to you. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I get the same error as you now. Ok this I can work with. It was a version problem. Thanks for your help Martijn Pieters

Comment: @user1009091: Glad you got things to work better now; once you authenticate remember to retrieve the token with `token = response.headers['authorization']`, then use that token on requests as a header again: `headers={'authorization': token}`.